# make RVM also load gems at vendor/gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I have a project (tracks) that ships its gems under `vendor/gems`. Some of these gems are no longer available trough rubygems, so a `rake gems:install` fails.

I want rubygems to load gems from both the `rvm-gem-dirs` (`/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@tracks, /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global`) and from the `vendor/gems`.

How can I add such a dir to the rubygems load path? Is that possible at all?

Comment: You can convert a Rails 2 app to bundler, then in your gemfile: gem 'coolthing', :path => 'vendor/gems/coolthing-3.2.8'

Comment: @Unixmonkey: I know, but the main problem is one "vendored" gem that is no longer avaliable anywhere. Though I guess I can include that in the Gemfile with the `:path` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the vendor/gems directory to the GEM_PATH environment variable.

```
GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH:/home/berkes/your_project/vendor/gems
```