# Include unpacked (vendor/gems/*) gems in rvm gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I have an application in Rails 2.3.11, with several bundled gems under `APP_ROOT/vendor/gems`. Rails itself is frozen under `APP_ROOT/vendor/rails`.

At first, I thought that I [needed to add the vendor dir to the rubygems load path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504337/make-rvm-also-load-gems-at-vendor-gems). But once I did that, the unpacked gems were still not available.

In the gemset, I can install all the gems one a time by hand, with `gem install foo`, but that will install the gem, instead of using the one shipped in the app. Same when I convert it to bundler and `bundle install`. The gems were unpacked, because some were modified or are not available online.

Is this something that I should solve in RVM? Or in Rails? Should I include some load-path somewhere to make the app pick up and understand the code under vendor/ ?

**Solution** The problem was RedCloth, which cannot be shipped bundled, because it needs to be buiit against the system's extensions somehow. Installing RedCloth system-wide solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was RedCloth, which cannot be shipped bundled, because it needs to be buiit against the system's extensions somehow. Installing RedCloth system-wide solves the problem.